# XNA Side Scrolling Shooter - How can I have bullets carry a value and reference that value later?

Tags: c#, xna, game-engine

**Premise:**

I'm independently developing a side-scrolling shoot 'em up game that involves a player shooting 3 different bullet types (we'll call these type 1, type 2, and type 3).  A player switches between these bullet types to take out different enemies (EX:  Type 1 bullet kills type 2 enemies; type 2 bullet kills type 1 enemies) if that makes sense.

In my Game1.cs, under the Update method, I have a simple workaround for each enemy that if bulletType = x, bullet will collide with enemy and do damage if it is weak to that specific type of bullet.  **Code for that:**

```
//PlayerBullet vs Enemy
for (int i = 0; i < player.bulletList.Count; i++)
{
    if (player.bulletType == 1)
    {
        if (player.bulletList[i].hitBox.Intersects(e.hitBox))
        {
            //destroy bullet and damage ship
            player.bulletList[i].isVisible = false;
            e.isVisible = false;

            //Score
            hud.playerScore += 20;

            //Explosion
            explosionList.Add(new Explosion(Content.Load<Texture2D>("explosion3"), new Vector2(e.position.X, e.position.Y)));

            //Sound
            sm.explodeSound.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

In the player class, bullet type is switched by pressing numpad keys (Num1 = bulletType 1, Num2 = bulletType2, etc.).  Each of these bullets have a corresponding texture associated with them.

The firing rate of these individual bullets is fast enough to look like a solid line when drawn on the screen.

**Problem:**

When a player shoots a line of Type 1 Bullets to kill Type 2 Enemies and then switches bulletType to Type 2 Bullets before the line of Type 1 Bullets collides with the Type 2 Enemies, the bullets will NOT collide even though the texture is of Bullet Type 1.

Basically, when a player switches bulletTypes, it changes the bulletType for ALL DRAWN bullets on screen rather than just the bullets fired after switching bulletType.  I need to have my bullets carry a value and I need to be able to switch that value on the fly whenever a player inputs a key.  I am unsure of how to do this.  I have a Bullet Class who's constructor takes a value of "bulletType", that is used when the Shoot function is called by the player pressing the corresponding button.

Bullet Class Constructor:

```
public Bullet(Texture2D newTexture, int newBulletType)
{
    velocity = 10;
    texture = newTexture;
    isVisible = false;
    bulletType = newBulletType;
}
```

Shoot function:

```
public void ShootYellow()
{
    //Shoot only when delay resets
    if (bulletDelay >= 0)
        bulletDelay--;

    //Create bullet at delay zero on player
    if (bulletDelay <= 0)
    {
        //Sound Effect
        //sm.playerShootSound.Play();

        Bullet newBullet = new Bullet(bulletYellowTexture, bulletType); //Create Bullet
        newBullet.position = new Vector2(position.X + 6 - newBullet.texture.Width / 2, position.Y + 30); //Spawn location of bullet

        //Make bullet visible
        newBullet.isVisible = true;

        //Add bullet to list
        if (bulletList.Count() < 256)
            bulletList.Add(newBullet);
    }

    //reset delay
    if (bulletDelay == 0)
        bulletDelay = 0;
}
```

At the very least, I would at least like all of the drawn textures to update with the bulletType switch.  So that all the drawn bullet textures switch with the current bulletType selected.

Comment: How many bullet types are there?  Would keeping another list, `List<Bullet2>` work?

Comment: The question is unclear if the behavior is what it *does* or if it is what it *should do*. In the above code (assuming `Bullet.texture/bulletType` is an *instance field*), the texture *won't change* when the weapon type is switched. If it does change then `Bullet.texture/bulletType` is altering shared state or the objects are otherwise being rendered incorrectly.

Comment: @Seth:  3 Bullet types thus far, could go up to 6 later.  But I think having separate lists for each might work, it would just be very demanding later.

Comment: @user2217822 Sure, it could expand and get complex.  But if each bullet also has different logic, then you will have complexity no matter what you do.  At least with independent lists, you always know where to apply the given logic.  And rather than having to filter one list for every bullet type every frame, you can optimize each list independently.